# AngularJS $http using service fired on Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, angularjs-service

i am using angular services to get the data from the server.
the problem is when the app is init then the default data is shown for 1 -2 days.

Then there are "click" events. on teh page. for every click there has to be an $http and fetch the data, teh problem is the click events trigger but i dont get a refreshed data.

Service

```
var sent = angular.module("sentAnalysis",["ngRoute"]);
var log = console.log.bind(console);


'use strict';
sent.service('Sentiments', function ($http) 
{
    var sentiments = [];
    return {
        getAjax: function(api,callback) {
            var cb = callback || angular.noop;
            if(sentiments.length !== 0) {
                cb(sentiments);
            }else{
                $http.get(api)
                    .success(function(result) 
                    {

                    sentiments = result;
                    cb(result);
                    })
                    .error(function() {
                        cb();
                    })
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The controller looks like this. I have added reference for document.getElementByid("") inside the landingCtrl.

```
document.getElementById("yesterday").addEventListener("click",function()
{


    var d1 = Sentiments.getDaysAgo(1);
    var startDate =  Sentiments.formatDate(d1);
    var d2 = Sentiments.getDaysAgo(0);
    var endDate =  Sentiments.formatDate(d2);
    log("Yesterday Data");
    log(startDate + " "+endDate);
    var api = "http://localhost:3000/api/sentiment?startDate="+startDate+"&endDate="+endDate;

    Sentiments.getAjax(api,function(res) 
    {


        if(res.status==true)
        {   

        }

        //Create Charts For Data
    }); /*AJAX ENDS*/
});




document.getElementById("tomorrow").addEventListener("click",function()
{


    var d1 = Sentiments.getDaysAgo(1);
    var startDate =  Sentiments.formatDate(d1);
    var d2 = Sentiments.getDaysAgo(0);
    var endDate =  Sentiments.formatDate(d2);
    log("Yesterday Data");
    log(startDate + " "+endDate);
    var api = "http://localhost:3000/api/sentiment?startDate="+startDate+"&endDate="+endDate;

    Sentiments.getAjax(api,function(res) 
    {


        if(res.status==true)
        {   

        }

        //Create Charts For Data
    }); /*AJAX ENDS*/
});
```

When i click on buttons on the UI i dont see any response coming.
I have functions inside my callback which gets executed once i get the response.
Also please suggest if there are any other way to get and update data for events uisng $http.

ng-click is also giving some results.

Comment: Why are you using document.getElementById? We are in 2015...

Comment: Angular, you doing it wrong. Where did you learn this? Please study this, it will help you: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide